# Find the most recent date and output value by group

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I want to display the most recent value only for each group.

Example from CSV below: The total amount of Bagels, of the Cinnamon Raisin variety, were collected on three separate sampling periods: May 2017, March 2017, and November 2016 with their amounts being: 300, 100, and 20 respectively.

I've taken the year and month, combined them, and converted them into a number format so I can do a d3.max to locate the most recent (highest) value. The highest would be 42856 (May 2017), but I want to display the amount (300) instead of the d3.max amount.

```
breakfastItem,gluten,breakfastItemType,month,year,dateCode,value
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,May,2017,42856,300
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,March,2017,42795,100
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,November,2016,42675,20
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,February,2017,42767,50
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,November,2016,42675,30
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,March,2016,42430,100
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2018,43132,200
Bagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2016,42401,201
```

Here was my Javascript:

```
d3.csv("Breakfast.csv",function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.value = +d.value;
            d.year = +d.year;
            d.dateCode = +d.dateCode;
        });

        var breakfastCombinations = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.breakfastItem; })
        .key(function(d) {return d.breakfastItemType; })
        .rollup(function(oldestDate) { 
            return d3.max(oldestDate, function(d) {
                return d.dateCode; });
            })
        .entries(data);
        document.getElementById("breakfastjson").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(breakfastCombinations,false,2); 

    });
```

Which pops out my JSON as

```
 {
    "key": "Bagel",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Cinnamon Raisin",
        "value": 42856
      },
      {
        "key": "Blueberry",
        "value": 42767
      },
      {
        "key": "Plain",
        "value": 43132
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I want the "value" to be the total amount of Bagels of that type, instead of the dateCode. Like this:

```
  {
    "key": "Bagel",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Cinnamon Raisin",
        "value": 300
      },
      {
        "key": "Blueberry",
        "value": 50
      },
      {
        "key": "Plain",
        "value": 200
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to use this dateCode to identify the information to display for a lot of different pieces of information (like Month, Year, etc.). I've tried combinations like:

```
        .rollup(function(oldestDate) { 
        return d3.max(oldestDate, function(d) {
            return d.dateCode; }).value;
        })
```

And

```
        .rollup(function(oldestDate) { 
        return d3.max(oldestDate, function(d) {
            return d.dateCode.value; });
        })
```

But I can't seem to find the right syntax to display it. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sort the `oldestDate` array of objects and get the `value` property of the first one, which is the highest:

```
.rollup(function(oldestDate) {
    return oldestDate.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.dateCode - a.dateCode
    })[0].value
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `breakfastItem,gluten,breakfastItemType,month,year,dateCode,value
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,May,2017,42856,300
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,March,2017,42795,100
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,November,2016,42675,20
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,February,2017,42767,50
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,November,2016,42675,30
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,March,2016,42430,100
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2018,43132,200
Bagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2016,42401,201`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  d.year = +d.year;
  d.dateCode = +d.dateCode;
  return d;
});

var breakfastCombinations = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItem;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItemType;
  })
  .rollup(function(oldestDate) {
    return oldestDate.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.dateCode - a.dateCode
    })[0].value
  })
  .entries(data);

console.log(breakfastCombinations)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works great, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!